# How to build object like directory tree structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-structures

i am building an file manager in html [demo here](http://www.prepbootstrap.com/bootstrap-template/file-manager), and i get the file routes as string array in c# like that `["file.exe","folder1/",folder1/file.xml","folder1/subfolder1/","folder1/subfolder1/file.docx"]`. The question is... how pass this array to an structure in c#  to return in ASP Web API? the structure need to be like that

```
 [
    {
        "text": "folder1", 
        "iconCls": "constant folder icon",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "subfolder1",
                "iconCls": "constant folder icon",
                "folderData":[
                    {
                       "icon": "constant file icon", 
                       "text": "file.docx"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
        "folderData":[
             {
                "icon": "constant file icon", 
                "text": "file.xml"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be sufficient objects for your task:

```
public class FolderData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Image IconCls { get; set; }
}

public class Folder
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Image IconCls { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> Items { get; set; }

    public List<FolderData> FolderDatas { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think this structure can not store a folder inside another folder, right? There would be only one level of folders with n folders and files

Comment: why use FolderData property? Sorry, I t don't understand very well, what about a subfolder with folders and files inside?

Comment: In this structure you can store other `Folder` objects in the `Items` list and create a tree like structure

Comment: `FolderData` is taken from your example JSON

Comment: oh you're right... i want to use the items property to store the subfolders and  FolderData to store the files inside in a folder/subfolder.

Comment: Ah, I understand. In that case there needs to be a `List<FolderData>`. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: thanks for your help! now i will trying to convert the string array to this object.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent C# class:

```
public class Directory
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string iconCls { get; set; }
    public List<FolderData> folderData { get; set; }
    public List<Directory> items { get; set; }

    public class FolderData
    {
        public string icon { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string iconCls { get; set; }
        public List<FolderData> folderData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use some useful online tools to work with json:

[Json viewer](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)

[C# class generator from json](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: I think this doesnt really meet the requirements. What if the item has subitems, too? Why is FolderData a List?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé you are right, it's just c# class generated with tool. I'll modify it

Comment: Now you have a useless class `Item` in there. If you remove it, you'll basically end up with the same code I've provided ;-)

Comment: Also the name `Directory` could lead to problems because it is also use in the .Net framework and will most likely be used in this application.